# Generalizing a function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am doing same step for different variables in my three functions.

```
 SumPosition_Channel *posChannel;
 bool isLoop;
 cont->GetPositionChannel(&posChannel);
 isLoop = posChannel->getChannelLoop();
 checkBoxChannelLoop->setChecked(isLoop);


SumRotation_Channel *rotChannel;
bool isLoop;
cont->GetRotationChannel(&rotChannel);
isLoop = rotChannel->getChannelLoop();
checkBoxChannelLoop->setChecked(isLoop);


SumScaling_Channel *scaChannel;
bool isLoop;
cont->GetScalingChannel(&scaChannel);
isLoop = scaChannel->getChannelLoop();
checkBoxChannelLoop->setChecked(isLoop);
```

Can I generalize them into one function?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why don't you use references when passing the pointer to the `GetXChannel` functions? And unless there's some inheritance and polymorphism involved, why use pointers at all?

Comment: As for your problem, why not use templates? Create a templated function doing all that, and rewrite `GetXChannel` into a templated function that you can specialize (and I recommend it *returns* the object instead of passing arguments).

Comment: @Some programmer dude i have inheritance involved in this .

Comment: @Some programmer dude i tried using Templates but i am bit confused about how to write code for this situation.

Comment: Why do all three use the same checkbox?

Comment: @ Ulrich Eckhardt These are different animation channels of a object when we choose any channel  o then it updates the checkbox with the information whether it is looped or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is using templates, not only for the code shown but also for the `GetXChannel` function.

Something like

```
// In the class for "cont"
template<typename T>
T* GetChannel();

// Specialization for SumPosition_Channel
template<>
SumPosition_Channel* GetChannel()
{
    SumPosition_Channel* channel = new SumPosition_Channel;
    // Other SumPosition_Channel specific initialization...
    return channel;
}

// Same for the rest of the channels
```

If you don't need any channel-specific initialization then just

```
// In the class for "cont"
template<typename T>
T* GetChannel()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Then this can be called easily from a templated function for the code you have:

```
template<typename T>
T* foo(ContType const* cont, CheckBoxChannelLoopType* checkBoxChannelLoop)
{
    T* channel = cont->GetChannel<T>();
    checkBoxChannelLoop->setChecked(channel->getChannelLoop());
    return channel;
}
```

---

Instead of raw non-owning pointers as shown in the examples above, I would recommend using either [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) if a "channel" can have only one single owner at a time, or [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) if there can be multiple simultaneous owners.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple via overloaded functions, especially if you didn't design the interface for those classes.

```
void GetChannel(SumPosition_Channel** channel,WhateverTypeThisIs* checkBoxChannelLoop, ContType* cont);
void GetChannel(SumRotation_Channel** channel,WhateverTypeThisIs* checkBoxChannelLoop, ContType* cont);
void GetChannel(GetScalingChannel** channel,WhateverTypeThisIs* checkBoxChannelLoop, ContType* cont);
```

in each of those functions simply call the corresponding function.
i.e.

```
void GetChannel(SumPosition_Channel** channel, WhateverTypeThisIs* checkBoxChannelLoop, ContType* cont)
{
 bool isLoop;
 cont->GetPositionChannel(&channel);
 isLoop = channel->getChannelLoop();
 checkBoxChannelLoop->setChecked(isLoop);
}
```

If you designed the interface, I suggest overloading those functions inside the actual cont class, as then you would need to type less.

Comment: The issue here is cont->GetPositionChannel(&channel); this changes with the variable type.

Comment: For rotation it will be cont->GetRotationChannel(&channel)

Comment: Don't forget getScalingChannel too!

Comment: that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generalize that using templates and overloading concepts.

```
template <typename T>
void func () { // your method Signature here
    T *channel;
    bool isLoop;
    cont->GetChannel(&channel); // overload the GetChannel() in the "cont" class type
    isLoop = rotChannel->getChannelLoop();
    checkBoxChannelLoop->setChecked(isLoop);
}
```

Now you can call the function with respective type.

Remember to overload the GetChannel() method in the "cont" class type for each of the template arguments type.

Hope this helps, Thanks.